# Xamarin Bindings Library interface not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an interface in my bindings library. It is being generated into C#, and it looks like this:

```
namespace XYZ.Sdk.Communication
{
    public partial interface ICommunicationManager : IJavaObject
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

There are no compilation errors or warnings in the build output regarding the interface. The only two places the word ICommunicationManager appears is where the CS file is created, and then when it is passed in with the CSC arguments.

In another class, the interface is then used as a return type:

```
public static unsafe global::XYZ.Sdk.Communication.ICommunicationManager CommunicationManager ()
```

The above code fails to compile because "The type or namespace name 'ICommunicationManager' does not exist in the namespace 'XYZ.Sdk.Communication'".

Why is it that the interface is being generated in a CS file, is passed into the compiler, does not give any errors, and yet it is unavailable elsewhere in the library?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: It was only an IntelliSense error. Deleted my SUO file and restarted VS and all is working.